# How do I reset pointer properties?

Tags: python, add-on

I am trying to write some code that adds a light object to a global dictionary when it's selected in one of the three pointers available. However, an issue arises when attempting to remove one of the pointers or just clearing all of them.

I've attempted to write the code so that whenever a pointer is removed using the "remove_light" operator I've created, the selected pointer and all of the ones added after it will be cleared as well as removed from the global dictionary. The number of light sources will also be decreased by however many pointers are removed. I can't get this code to work, though, and even with the "full reset" code that I've written, once the pointers are added back they still contain the object that was selected for them (showing that they have not been set equal to 'None' as I had intended) and the count of light sources returns back to what it was before the "full reset" instead of starting over from zero.

Can anybody help me work this out?

Goals:

- Write code that behaves similarly to the "full reset" code that I've written, but only affects a specific pointer as well as all of the pointers added after it.
- Fix "full reset" code so that the pointers don't still contain selected objects once added back and the count of light sources starts back at zero.

My Code:

````
import bpy

# Global dictionary to add the light source(s) to:

global light_source_list
light_source_list = {}

# Object Sorting:

def poll_is_light(self, obj):
    return obj.type == 'LIGHT'

# Properties:

class ADDON_properties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    #Integer Property representing max amount of light sources you can select:
    
    num_lights: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name= "Number of Light Sources",
        description= "",
        min=0,
        max=3,
    )
    
    # Light Source Pointers:
    
    light_pointer1 : bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        name= "", 
        description= "None", 
        type= bpy.types.Object,
        poll= poll_is_light,
    )
    
    light_pointer2 : bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        name= "", 
        description= "None", 
        type= bpy.types.Object,
        poll= poll_is_light,
    )
    
    light_pointer3 : bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        name= "", 
        description= "None", 
        type= bpy.types.Object,
        poll= poll_is_light,
    )

# Operator for adding a new light source pointer:

class ADDON_OT_add_light(bpy.types.Operator):
    
    bl_label = ''
    bl_idname = "add_light.operator"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'RNGenius'
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        scene = context.scene
        if not scene: return False
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        if mytool.num_lights >= 3:
            return False
        
        return True
    
    def execute(self, context):
        context.scene.my_tool.num_lights += 1
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
# Operator for removing the most recent light source pointer:
    
class ADDON_OT_remove_light(bpy.types.Operator):
    
    bl_label = ''
    bl_idname = "remove_light.operator"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'RNGenius'
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        scene = context.scene
        if not scene: return False
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        if mytool.num_lights < 2:
            return False
        
        return True
    
    def execute(self, context):
        context.scene.my_tool.num_lights -= 1
        return {'FINISHED'}

# Main UI Panel:
 
class ADDON_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "ADDON"
    bl_idname = "ADDON_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "ADDON"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
       
# Light Source(s) Pointers UI:
        
        light_sources = context.scene.my_tool.num_lights
        
        layout.label(text= "Light Source(s):")
        layout.prop(mytool, "light_pointer1")
        
        # Determines whether or not a light object has been selected for the pointer:
        
        light_pointer1_status = bpy.context.scene.my_tool.light_pointer1
        light_pointer2_status = bpy.context.scene.my_tool.light_pointer2
        light_pointer3_status = bpy.context.scene.my_tool.light_pointer3
        
        # If a light object has been selected for the first pointer, then add another pointer:
        
        if light_sources > 1 and light_pointer1_status != None:
            layout.prop(mytool, "light_pointer2")
            
        # If a light object has been selected for the second pointer, then add another pointer:
            
        if light_sources > 2 and light_pointer1_status != None:
            layout.prop(mytool, "light_pointer3")
        
        # If a light object has been selected for the first pointer, then show "add_light" operator:
        
        if light_pointer1_status != None:
            layout.operator("add_light.operator", text= "New Light", icon= "PLUS")
            
        # If there is more than one light source, then show "remove_light" operator:
            
        if light_sources > 1 and light_pointer1_status != None:
            layout.operator("remove_light.operator", text= "Remove Light", icon= "TRASH")
            
        light_source_count = 0
        
        # If an item is selected for a pointer, increase the amount of light sources by one
        # and then add it to the global dictionary:
        
        if light_pointer1_status != None:
            light_source_count += 1
            light_source_list.update({light_pointer1_status.name: light_source_count})
        if light_pointer2_status != None:
            light_source_count += 1
            light_source_list.update({light_pointer2_status.name: light_source_count})
        if light_pointer3_status != None:
            light_source_count += 1
            light_source_list.update({light_pointer3_status.name: light_source_count})
            
        # If the first pointer is cleared then reset the amount of light sources to zero,
        # clear the global dictionary, and clear all of the other pointers:
        
        if light_pointer1_status == None and light_source_count > 0: # <-- "full reset" code.
            light_source_count = 0
            light_source_list.clear()
            light_pointer2_status = None
            light_pointer3_status = None
            
        # ***INSERT CODE FOR DECREASING LIGHT SOURCES HERE*** <-- Need to be able to reset all pointers
        #                                                         above whatever pointer is cleared
        #                                                         without resetting the ones below it.
        
classes = [ADDON_properties,  
           ADDON_PT_main_panel, 
           ADDON_OT_add_light, 
           ADDON_OT_remove_light]
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type= ADDON_properties)
  
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: Don't use global state variables in Blender addons. You also shouldn't be doing anything in draw() other than drawing layout. If you want a list of all the lights that are picked, write a function that reads from bpy.context.scene.my_tool and returns it instead of using a global variable. And if you want to run code when a property is changed, use the update= arg to PointerProperty, not draw().

Comment: To add to the comment, you should use a [CollectionProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CollectionProperty.html) to store object pointers. you can simply do `col.clear()` to remove references.